# How can I merge texts inside my JSON files

Tags: python, json

The thing I have is like this:

```
 {
  "locale": "WORLD",
  "articles": [

    {
        "url": "Second url"
    },
    {
        "url": "Second url"       
    }
]
}
```

and another file containing this:

```
{
  "locale": "WORLD",
  "articles": [

    {
        "url": "First url"
    },
    {
        "url": "First url(1)"       
    }
]
}
```

so finally I would have this:

```
{
  "locale": "WORLD",
  "articles": [

    {
        "url": "First url"
    },
    {
        "url": "First url(1)"       
    },
    {
        "url": "Second url"
    },
    {
        "url": "Second url"       
    }
]
}
```

Actually I have thousands of such blocks (I just simplified them), and I have to divide them for train (80 percent) and test (20percent) sets. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please cf. my answer for the aggreagation and processing algorithm steps I understood fomr the question. Hopefully this helped. I wonder though, what you mean with "[...]have to divide them for train(80 percent) and test(20percent) sets" - could you explain by editing the question to help us help you? That would be great! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest, you simply deserialize-transform-serialize as transformation scenario.

A non-compacting merge (leaving redundant dicts/objects the kind `{"url": "whatever"}` being elemtn of "articles" key list as is:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
import json


JSON_TEXTS = (
    ('{"locale": "WORLD", "articles": ['
     '{"url": "Second url"},{"url": "Second url"}]}'),
    ('{"locale": "WORLD", "articles": ['
     '{"url": "First url"}, {"url": "First url(1)"}]}'))


combined = {'locale': 'WORLD', 'articles': []}
for json_text in JSON_TEXTS:
    parsed = json.loads(json_text)
    if parsed['locale'] == combined['locale']:
        urls = ([v['url'] for v in parsed['articles']])
        for url in urls:
            combined['articles'].append({'url': url})

print(combined)
```

yields:

```
{'locale': 'WORLD', 'articles': [{'url': u'Second url'}, {'url': u'Second url'}, {'url': u'First url'}, {'url': u'First url(1)'}]}
```

or beautified / reformatted as JSON:

```
{
  "locale": "WORLD",
  "articles": [
    {
      "url": "Second url"
    },
    {
      "url": "Second url"
    },
    {
      "url": "First url"
    },
    {
      "url": "First url(1)"
    }
  ]
}
```

A compacting merge (removing redundant dicts/objects the kind `{"url": "whatever"}` being elemtn of "articles" key list:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
import json


JSON_TEXTS = (
    ('{"locale": "WORLD", "articles": ['
     '{"url": "Second url"},{"url": "Second url"}]}'),
    ('{"locale": "WORLD", "articles": ['
     '{"url": "First url"}, {"url": "First url(1)"}]}'))


combined = {'locale': 'WORLD'}
unique_urls = set()
for json_text in JSON_TEXTS:
    parsed = json.loads(json_text)
    if parsed['locale'] == combined['locale']:
        urls = set([v['url'] for v in parsed['articles']])
        unique_urls |= urls

combined['articles'] = [{'url': u} for u in unique_urls]
print(combined)
```

On my machine this yields (with here python2):

```
{'locale': 'WORLD', 'articles': [{'url': u'First url'}, {'url': u'Second url'}, {'url': u'First url(1)'}]}
```

or beautified / reformatted as JSON:

```
{
  "locale": "WORLD",
  "articles": [
    {
      "url": "First url"
    },
    {
      "url": "Second url"
    },
    {
      "url": "First url(1)"
    }
  ]
}
```

Works also with python3 out of the box. You would of course have to use `json.load(...)`, and `json.dump()` (or a self-made serializer in case order matters) to read input data from and put the filtered / combined data to disk.

Now this uses strings for ease of display in ana answer, in real life you would have to go over files and write the results.

So in essential: Prepare minimal dict to hold results and intermediate set to keep only unique values of url keys, than go over every in json text (file data) look if locale value matches, extract the values of the url keys in objects of array articles, into a local set, perform a union of the collecting set (unique_urls and the urls named local set from the json text input at hand.

After the loop combine all urls from uniqe set as values for keys in separate objects in array value of articles. Done.

The order of keys upon serialization is depending on some factors, due to the nature of python dict implementation (hashes with collision mitiagtion and thus also some sequence of insertion orders) and version of python.

If you want eg. always the grouping key to be output first, you will have to ensure that by additional measures. In general consumers of JSON text objects (the dicts of JSON) should not depend on the order the keys appear on wire or in file.

Also if you want to go once over all files and have N different keys you want to aggregate on (i.e. values of the locale key on input, you would simply create combined as sequence of dicts or dict of dict and in the loop over the external files for every file select the applicable output combination target (dict) have an isolated set for these targets and then output after your done accordingly N files.